# Appending multiple new lines to a buffer (instead of "^M")

Tags: buffers, functions

I'm trying to create a buffer for a specific purpose, and for that, I need to add newlines to it to get it to be the same height as my current window. My first idea, using `call append("^", repeat("\r", winheight(win_getid())))` didn't work (all it did was append `^M` several times over to a single line), and I can't seem to find a solution anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append()` (or `appendbufline()`) do not allow `\r` or `\n` to insert new lines. You should use List instead. For instance,

```
call appendbufline(l:bufnr, '$', repeat([''], winheight(winnr())))
```

Comment: > append() (or appendbufline()) do not allow \r or \n to insert new lines. Thx, for HOURS I've tried to figure out why this does not work: :append(0,'\r\r')
Vim inserts `^M^M` on the first line.
`ff=unix` is set.
Why does the vim doc has not mentioned it that `append()` doesn't accept `\r`?!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This seems more like a reply than an answer, so I'm going to convert it to a comment. RE: the help, it does say `Otherwise append {text} as one text line below line {lnum} in the current buffer.`

Answer (score 2):

First off, are you sure you need to add actual content to your buffer? If the goal is just to get it the same height as a single, current window, there's a much simpler method in normal mode:

```
<C-W>=
```

Or in Vimscript:

```
:wincmd =
```

The problem with your append command is that you're passing a string, which explicitly tells it add the content to a single line. To add multiple lines, you should instead pass a list:

```
call append("^", repeat([''], winheight(win_getid())))
```